# Why does electric current not flow through the galvanometer (the null detector) in a balanced Wheatstone bridge?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

As electric current will flow in path with zero resistance when a zero resistance path and finite resistance path are in parallel combinations. In a Wheatstone bridge, the resistors have a finite resistance and the resistance of the galvanometer can be considered as either negligible or finite.

So,

- Either all the current must flow through the galvanometer
- Or some current must flow through the galvanometer as is it in a parallel connection with the resistors
  But, why doesn't the electrons flow through the galvanometer?

Comment: Low resistance does not alone mean current flowing. You still need a potential difference (voltage) to create the current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this image from Wikipedia:

[image: By Rhdv - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=2888809]

Consider $R_1 = R_2 = R_3 = 2\Omega$ and the unknown $R_\text{x} = 1 \Omega$, but we don't know that yet.

Also consider that the galvanometer is not yet in place.

Now there will be more current through B than through D. Also the potential of D will be in the middle of the potential difference of the batterie's terminals **while B will be at a lower potential** than D because the voltage divider $R_3$-$R_\text{x}$ is not symmetric. Current will flow through the galvanometer from B to D.

This tells us to decrease $R_2$. At half the initial resistance, the whole thing becomes symmetric because now D is at the same potential as B. There will be no current between two nodes at the same potential, no matter the resitance of the galvanometer.

Answer (score 1):

> As electric current will flow in path with zero resistance when a zero
>   resistance path and finite resistance path are in parallel
>   combinations.
>   ... 
>   But, why doesn't the electrons flow through the galvanometer?

First, that galvanometer isn't in parallel with any of the resistors in the Wheatstone bridge so your logic here doesn't work.

Second, *if* there is a current through the galvanometer, the bridge cannot be balanced.  You can conclude this without resorting to any equations as follows (refer to the diagram):

[image]

To say that the bridge is balanced is to say that the open-circuit bridge voltage $V_{out}$ is zero which implies both

(1) the voltage across $R_1$ *equals* the voltage across $R_3$

(2) the voltage across $R_2$ *equals* the voltage across $R_4$

Carefully note that (1) and (2) hold just when there is zero current from $C$ to $D$ (there must be zero current since there is an open-circuit between those nodes).

Now, replace the open-circuit with an ideal wire (short-circuit) between nodes $C$ and $D$ and see that now

- $R_1$ is in parallel with $R_3$
- $R_2$ is in parallel with $R_4$

Since parallel connected circuit elements have identical voltage across, it follows that (1) and (2) still hold and so conclude that, since a circuit solution is unique, the current through the wire and the open-circuit must be equal, i.e., the current through the wire is zero.